# Does Firebird Embedded Server provide multiple thread concurrency?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird-embedded

Firebird Database comes in several flavours. One of them is the Windows Embedded server.

I wish to embed it in my application which runs multiple threads. Each thread may access the server concurrently

Has anyone had any experience using it? Does Firebird Embedded Server provide multiple thread concurrency?

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple process concurrency"? As Firebird embedded can only by accessed by the process running it, the use of "multiple process" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I mean multiple threads accessing it.

Answer (score 3):

As documented in the Firebird 2.5 release notes [Thread-safe Client Library](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes254.html#rnfb25-engine-thrdsafe):

> ## Thread-safe Client Library
>
> Dmitry Yemanov
> Vladyslav Khorsun
> Alex Peshkov
>
> Tracker reference [CORE-707](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-707).
>
> The client libraries, including the embedded one, can now be used in multi-threaded applications without any application-level synchronization.